# Error : Manifest merger failed sdk:minSdkVersion

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I was Import eclips project to android studio but I have this Error when build the project :

`Error:Execution failed for task :myCHAT:processDebugManifest.
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 17 declared in library [MyCHAT:uIMaterialdialogsLib:unspecified] E:\Android\MyChat-MessangerTemplatePack\MyCHAT\myCHAT\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\MyCHAT\uIMaterialdialogsLib\unspecified\AndroidManifest.xml
Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.afollestad.materialdialogs" to force usage`

AndroidManifest is :

```
<manifest package="com.afollestad.materialdialogs">

<application />
```

Gradle code :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 17
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile files('libs/classes.jar')
}
```

Comment: change `minSdkVersion 17` to `14` in your gradle

Comment: @Logic it's Correct many thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete Or Comment line :

```
compile files('libs/classes.jar')
```